# Client/Sever application on Java, Android

Tags: java, android, xml, sockets

I must create app such as tcp/ip client for Android which can connect (with socket) to server and listen port; server app (exist) give .xml file and client on android take it. I'm new developer and I don't know how to do that. Help me please, give me an example.

Comment: Sockets in android is just like the Java sockets, actually they are java sockets itself, is that what you want?